# ASP.Net Webforms and MVC3 global.asax/routes being ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, axd

I have a mixed ASP.Net and MVC3 project. Site delivers both aspx and MVC views. Essentially working EXCEPT all .axd requests are being intercepted by MVC and causing exceptions:

The controller for path '*/Members/Chart.axd*' was not found or does not implement `IController`.

My routes look like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

.axd files are originally designed for asp.net controls; maybe they didn't anticipate third-party followers to add subfolders to these urls.

I probably didn't explain that right, but my point is that "{resource}.axd" assumes that the url is pointing to .axd file sitting in the site-root, and not in some subfolder.

Comment: hi Hari thanks for the reply.. when i publish on production i am getting the following error: "A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter. Parameter name: routeUrl" --- any ideas?